# Gets.chomp input comparison returning an error

Tags: ruby, numbers, integer, argument-error

I AM USING RUBY

ERROR: comparison of Integer with String failed (ArgumentError)

```
puts "Age: "
    age = gets.chomp
    if 0 < age < 130
```

I want the programm to allow the user to input all the numbers between 0 (not included) and 130 (included). How to do it?

Comment: From `:stdin` you receive strings. You need to convert it to integer before comparison: `0 < age.to_i < 130`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input is a string. Try something like this

```
puts "Age: "
user_input = gets.chomp
begin
  age = Integer(user_input)
  # your code
rescue ArgumentError
  puts "Age must be an integer"
end
```

Comment: Using `Integer()` over `to_i` is good as `to_i` will return zero for non-numeric strings.

Comment: What (begin) rescue (end) stands for?

Comment: BUT HOW TO ALLOW USER ONLY TO INPUT INTEGERS BETWEEN 0 AND 130?

Comment: The same way you were doing :)

Comment: This time your age is an integer. Oh, just, you can't do `< age <`. You need something like `if age >= 0 && age <= 130`

Comment: `begin` and `rescue` are used to check and recover from errors

Comment: Another way is using a range `if (0..130).include?(age)`